# Arch Linux legacy installation generating grub configuration file doesn't detect linux image

Tags: arch-linux, grub

I followed the installation guide of arch-linux 
(https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/installation_guide) to install the OS on a 32bit laptop in legacy mode. I loaded the iso with an USB Stick.

```
 lsblk
 NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE      RO TYPE    MOUNTPOINT
 loop0  7:0      0   513.1M    1 loop
 sda    8:0      0   149.1G    0 disk
 |-sda1 8:1      0   477M      0 part     /boot
 |-sda2 8:2      0   4G        0 part     [SWAP]
 |-sda3  8:3     0   144.6G    0 part     /
 sdb    8:16     1   29.3G     0 disk
 -sdb1  8:17     1   29.3G     0 part
  sr0   11:0     1   627M      0 rom
```

Installed grub without errors:

```
grub-install /dev/sda

Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

When I try to generate the configuration file the output is:

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg

Generating grub configuration file ...
done
```

After I reboot it loads into a grub console.

Comment: What was the command? Can you please add a link to the guide? AFAIK you don't need a boot partition for legacy MBR and maybe you chose the wrong partition.

Comment: @Freddy i added the link to the installation guide and added the commands. I also tried to install before without a boot partition and it was the same result. What do you mean by "maybe i chose the wrong partition"? In which step?

Comment: I still fail to see where the grub-installation is done in the guide (sorry, never installed arch myself). If you bootet from a USB stick and you didn't chroot to your root partition, you would use something like `grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda` to point grub to the right location (if your target filesystem is mounted on `/mnt`). You're using `grub2`, right? There's also an option to specify the boot directory, e.g. `--boot-directory=/mnt/boot`, but this shouldn't be necessary if the root already is your system root or if you used the `--root-directory` option.

Comment: Anyways, your `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` call should list your initrd's and kernel images and it seems your boot directory is somehow wrong. Are there any kernels and initrd's in `/boot`?

Comment: @Freddy no there are no Kernel images in my /boot folder

Comment: That explains things... Did you install the [essential packages](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/installation_guide#Install_essential_packages)?

Comment: @Freddy i ran "pacstrap -i /mnt base base-devel". I will reinstall and install "linux linux-firmware" Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, sounds reasonable. And after that do this Arch chroot thing `arch-chroot /mnt`, `grub-install /dev/sda` (I guess that's not needed) and `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Comment: If you didn't do it yet, then of course also the other steps in [Configure_the_system](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/installation_guide#Configure_the_system).

Comment: @Freddy You are my Hero! I reinstalled it atleast 10 times in the last 48 hours. It finally booted into arch linux. I also configured it. Somehow i missed the essential packages. Thank you so much i really appreciate your help!

Comment: Glad I could help! Could you please write a short answer so this question can be marked as resolved? You can [accept your own answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) after 2 days. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I hadn't downloaded the linux kernel from the essential packages (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/installation_guide#Install_essential_packages).

After reinstalling the system and using the command:

```
pacstrap /mnt base base-devel linux linux-firmware
```

grub could locate the kernel in my /boot folder.